# How to disable a particular field in a window

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

How to disable the marked field that attached here. I need to disable only this field when the time of fetching the data from the table.[image]

Answer (score 3):

Either

```
DISABLE <fieldname> WITH FRAME <framename> .
```

or

```
ASSIGN <fieldname>:SENSITIVE IN FRAME <framename> = FALSE .
```